# Meaning of "For a lawyer's office"

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gjiZ3E67e4U

Starting at the 32:48 mark

He said: "For a lawyers office, things are slow as shit down there."

I’m confusing something in this phrase, he’s not comparing something, right? Like the office lawyers are expected to move faster. What’s this “for a lawyers office" mean? As I understand "As a lawyers office" has more meaning. Please explain.

Is not in relation to the lawyers office,correct?

Comment: For, preposition: 9 "In relation to the expected norm of (something)" https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/for

Comment: But I google it and it sais lawyers offices are often very slow...

Comment: Lawyers offices may often be very slow compared to a "normal" office, but this office is very slow compared to other lawyers' offices.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to say is that "For a lawyer's office" is a fronting adverbial phrase. "As a lawyer's office" is not so idiomatic.

Next, there is an indirect comparison with what would be expected:

"For a lawyer's office, things are slow as shit down there." = "*Compared to the typical* lawyer's office, things are slow as shit down there."

OED gives

> **For**:
> **VI. Of attributed or assumed character; = as.**
>
> **19.a. In the character of, in the light of, *as the/an equivalent to*;**
>
> 1719   D. Defoe *Farther Adventures Robinson Crusoe* 256   *You'll be hanged for a Pirate.*
>
> 1845   M. Pattison in *Christian Remembrancer* Jan. 68   *Mere chronology..is often mistaken for history.*

You will see that **as** also works, *but does not work so well*.

Whereas "**as**" introduces a similarity, **for**, in this context tends to introduce an example:

**For** (preposition) = As an example of

"For a small man, (small men are not often strong) you are very strong."